# How to request data from producer at beginning position that does not exist in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, producer-consumer

I have a database with time series data and this data is sent to Kafka.

Many consumers build aggregations and reporting based on this data.
My Kafka cluster stores data with TTL for 1 day.

But how I can build a new report and run a new consumer from 0th position that does not exist in Kafka but exists in source storage.

For example - some callback for the producer if I request an offset that does not exist in Kafka?

If it is not possible please advise other architectural solutions. I want to use the same codebase to aggregate this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example - some callback for the producer if I request an offset
> that does not exist in Kafka?

If the data does not exist in Kafka, you cannot consume it much less do any aggregation on top of it.

Moreover, there is no concept of a *consumer* requesting a *producer*. Producer sends data to Kafka broker(s) and consumers consume from those broker(s). There is no *direct* interaction between a producer and a consumer as such.

---

Since you say that the data still exists in the source DB, you can fetch your data from there and reproduce it to Kafka.

When you produce that data again, they will be new messages which will be eventually consumed by the consumers as usual.
In case you would like to differentiate between initial consumption and re-consumption, you can produce these messages to a new topic and have your consumers consume from them.

Other way is to increase your TTL (I suppose you mean *retention* in Kafka when you say TTL) and then you can seek back to a *timestamp* in the consumers using the `offsetsForTimes(Map<TopicPartition,Long> timestampToSearch)` and `seek(TopicPartition topicPartition, long offset)` methods.